AppleScript encounters "Not authorized to send Apple events to System Events" on MacOS virtual machine
I'm running an automated test in Sauce Labs on MacOS 13 with the latest Chrome version available. The test I'm running gets the user's audio. I've included Chrome's fake device flags (https://webrtc.github.io/webrtc-org/testing/) in my Sauce config.yml file under the browserArgs option to supply Chrome's fake audio source (https://docs.saucelabs.com/web-apps/automated-testing/testcafe/yaml/#browserargs). Here are my Sauce configurations for Chrome & MacOS 13:
  - name: "Chrome in sauce on MacOS 13"
    platformName: "macOS 13"
    browserName: "chrome"
    browserArgs: [ "--no-sandbox", "--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream", "--use-fake-device-for-media-stream" ]
    src:
      - "tests/*-test.js"

The problem is that a MacOS microphone permission dialog appears during the Sauce test run and causes my test to fail because Chrome's fake audio wasn't allowed to play.

I'm trying to handle this mic permissions dialog on Sauce Labs by having my test execute this AppleScript to click the OK button:
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "UserNotificationCenter"
        click button "OK" of window 1
    end tell
end tell

The AppleScript works successfully to click the dialog's OK button when tested locally on my MacOS desktop. The script runs into the error execution error: Not authorized to send Apple events to System Events. when it tries to execute on Sauce Labs in Chrome & MacOS 13.
Is there a way to resolve the Not authorized error so my AppleScript can successfully click in Sauce Labs?
Is there another way to not have the MacOS microphone permissions dialog come up in Sauce Labs and have Chrome's fake audio play automatically during the test?
